# Ruby on Rails: simple_form + Twitter Bootstrap not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple sign_up form for new users on my site. I have ran the install for simple_form bootstrap...

```
rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

However, it's still not showing up and rendering as a normal simple_form.

Here is my form code:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name ), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>


    <%= f.input :username, :required => true, class: "form-control"%>
    <%= f.input :first_name, :required => true, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, :required => true, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.input :twitter, class: "form-control", type: "text", placeholder: "Username" %>
    <%= f.input :bio, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say it isn't rendering, do you mean there is an error generating the HTML? Or that the CSS isn't showing up? Or something else?

Comment: Apologies. I mean the CSS isn't showing up.

Comment: Do you see Boostrap stylesheets in app/assets/stylesheets?

Comment: I've never used simple_form, so I am feeling my way through this. However, I did notice the documentation says, "You have to be sure that you added a copy of the Twitter Bootstrap assets on your application." Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The sample application [here](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap) mentions how you need to download Bootstrap separately (they use curl) and place it in vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css.

Please try that.

Comment: I tried that and still got nothing. Perhaps this is an issue of the HTML not generating properly.

Comment: So you're sure it is in vendor/assets? Then do the "*= require_tree ." or "*= require boostrap" in the manifest. Check out this link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Bootstrap is not installed in your application or maybe you are trying to use Bootstrap 3. At the time I typed this on 2013-10-13, Simple Form did not support Bootstrap 3. See [here](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/pull/28) for more details.

So that means you need to add Bootstrap 2.x to your application and [Vidya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1347281/vidya) has provided some good direction already.

If you are interested in using a gem to add Bootstrap 2.x, then I've provided instructions for twitter-bootstrap-rails below. Be sure to review their [readme](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) as well in case I omitted something.

In your gemfile add:

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

Then at the rails console for your project run (I've assumed you want less support):

```
bundle install
rails generate bootstrap:install less
```

Depending on whether you want a fixed or static layout use one of the two lines below:

```
rails g bootstrap:layout application fixed
rails g bootstrap:layout application fluid
```

Finally, edit your application.css file (found in app/assets/stylesheets) so it has 'require bootstrap_and_overrides similar to the example below:

```
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap_and_overrides
*= require_tree .
```

I'm pretty sure this happens by default now but you might also want to confirm that you have 'require twitter/bootstrap in your application.js as well (found in app/assets/javascripts). An example from a project of mine is below:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

If it still doesn't work and you added this gem. Kindly let me know what version of ruby, rails, simple_form and twitter-bootstrap-rails you are using.