# Twitter bootstrap not working on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am following screencast about [twitter bootstrap basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics?autoplay=true) to try to understand bootstrap more, but for some reason when I go to localhost, my app has no styling.

I have tried the steps from github repo https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails as well.

I have also followed instruction from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437082/ruby-on-rails-simple-form-twitter-bootstrap-not-showing-up), but when I added the line `*= require bootstrap_and_overrides`, it shows `FileNotFound` error.

Here is what I did, after Rails new app `bootstrap_practice`:

```
rails g scaffold Product name price:decimal --skip-stylesheets
rake db:migrate
# added gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git' on gemfile (I have also tried just gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
bundle install
rails g bootstrap:install
```

I checked assets and it has the necessary assets.

Stylesheets (application.css)

```
*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

JS:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Lastly, my application.html.erb has

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I am pretty sure that is everything needed. Why is my application on localhost not styled?

Comment: I prefer using original gems from creators: `https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass` it worked great for me..

Comment: Super basic question, but what is the difference between `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem vs `bootstrap-sass` gem? Are they essentially doing the same thing (styling), but is the former gem "unofficial" gem?

Comment: Difference is the official gem using SASS but yours using LESS.
[SASS vs LESS](http://www.zingdesign.com/less-vs-sass-its-time-to-switch-to-sass/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An official SASS repo was released since the railscasts was released. (Rails comes with SASS out the box.)

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

The repo by seyhunak is maintained in LESS, which requires therubyracer too.

Comment: I just noticed that one has LESS and another SASS, what's the difference?

Comment: They are both CSS preprocessors. They add many features to CSS like variables and mixins. Using the SASS gem would let you customize bootstrap by overriding the styles in SASS, while the LESS gem would do the same in LESS. You would get access to all of the defined bootstrap variables for customization. Personally, I'm a fan of SASS.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've used twitter-bootstrap a lot of ways in Rails, and my favorite is with the `bh` gem.  [Bootstrap Helpers](http://fullscreen.github.io/bh/) on github.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'bh'

# application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag bootstrap_css %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag font_awesome_css %>
<%= javascript_include_tag bootstrap_js %>
```

All the assets are delivered through the CDN.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will check out bh-gem!